# Error importing module in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to import a module through Visual Basic.

Below is the code that I used to import the module :

```
Sub CreationMacroAuto()
   Dim Modulos As String

   Modulos = "C:\My_macro\macro.bas"

   With Workbooks("try.xlsm").VBProject
   .VBComponents.Import Modulos
   End With

   'assign value is the name of the sub in macro.bas
   Call assign_value()

End Sub
```

I am having an error 1004 : object defined error on this line :

```
With Workbooks("try.xlsm").VBProject
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Final Edit:**

```
Sub CreationMacroAuto()

Dim Modulos As String


    Modulos = "C:/users/Sun/Desktop/StackOverflow/assign_value.bas" 'change filepath to yours


    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Import Modulos

    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"), "callingNewSub"


End Sub


Sub callingNewSub()

    Call Module1.assign_value

End Sub
```

Put above code into one module. This code worked for me. You may also want to rename your Module1 to something else, for example "assign_value_mod", to reduce chance of errors.

---

---

**Original Answer and Edits:**

You need to add this reference to your code:

```
On Error Resume Next 'in case reference already exists

    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid _
        GUID:="{0002E157-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}", _
        Major:=5, Minor:=3

On Error GoTo 0
```

EDIT: In fact, the error may rather be with `Workbooks("try.xlsm")`, as you should write the whole filepath here... Or if it is the workbook where you are calling the code from, then just use `ThisWorkbook`

**EDIT2:** try this:

```
Sub CreationMacroAuto()

    Dim Modulos As String

    Modulos = "C:\My_macro\macro.bas"

    On Error Resume Next 'in case reference already exists

        ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid _
            GUID:="{0002E157-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}", _
            Major:=5, Minor:=3

    On Error GoTo 0

    With ThisWorkbook.VBProject
        .VBComponents.Import Modulos
    End With

    Call Module1.assign_value()

End Sub
```

As for calling a macro: don't write `Call macro.bas` but call the sub that is inside it. For example, the sub above is called `CreationMacroAuto()`, so you would call it `Call CreationMacroAuto()`.

Comment: I think I found the reason, it is because of the security. In other word, I need to manually allow  excel to enable the option for developper  to used the module. How can I automatised this part? Another question, when I import the module,I wrote a code that will call the module, 'Call macro.bas' but VBA did not recognised this module. I think its normal because, the module will not exist until I import it. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: The reference I showed you should be doing just that. Insert it to the beginning of your code. When you call macro afterwards, you should call the sub inside it, not the .bas file. If you do NOT want it to be called automatically, you need to disable events: `application.enableevents = false`

Comment: Can you write a proper code for me please? I am a newbie in VBA programming

Comment: I don't really know what you mean by proper code, but check Edit2, does that work?

Comment: Thanks for the good presentation. The problem about calling the function is that, the name of the module do not yet exist before the import. Thus when I am trying to launch the code, VBA tell me that it didn't recognised the function that I want to call. U proposed me to use 'application.enableevents = false'. where shoud I put this Line of code?

Comment: I don't quite understand, maybe you could edit your code into your question. I mean the code in which you try to call the new module. Why is it called before your import?

Comment: What is the module of assign_value called? The name that you see to the left, in the Project Explorer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113395/discussion-between-maximus-and-sun).